# How to simplify a an expression with exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this expression. I am not sure how to combine the terms with same exponent.

$\frac{4}{3} 3^m + 2 (-1^m) - 2 (3^{m - 1}) - 3 (-1^{m - 1})$

Comment: For one you can write $2(3^{m-1})$ as $\frac233^m$.

Comment: You can combine exponential terms if they have the same base not matter what the exponentials are. So you can simplify  $\frac{4}{3} 3^m  - 2 (3^{m - 1}) $ and $ 2 (-1^m)- 3 (-1^{m - 1})$ in the way as Gregory suggested.

Comment: Do you really mean $(-1^m)$ and $(-1^{m-1})$ (which are both always $-1$) rather than $(-1)^m$ and $(-1)^{m-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

$$4\cdot 3^{m-1} -2\cdot3^{m-1} +2(-1)^m+3(-1)^m=2\cdot3^{m-1}+5(-1)^m$$